# It seems that documents Liferay indexing is not done completely

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I have a problem with the Elastic indexation of the documents.

Many documents are not retrieved on research (on portlets and on administrations pages).

When I do the reindex by Administration page, I see on logs missing documents.

If I modify the document manualy, the document is retrieve on research.

What is the problem ?

Samuel

(Sorry for my bad english ;) )

Comment: This is not programming-related, thus off-topic on stackoverflow. Please carry it over to the Liferay forums or find a proper site in the stackexchange network (see [help/on-topic])

Comment: I try on StackOverflow because the Liferay forum is not very reactive ... :(
Maybe someone have solution

Comment: Well, with Devcon last week, people were busy doing other stuff. You might as well try Liferay's community slack. If you tried it there already, you forgot to post the link. Either way, the question is on-topic there, and off-topic here. And your question should have a lot more details anyway: Error messages, log file excerpts, steps to reproduce, exact version (see [ask])

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to incoherences on DB.
Table ddm_content was not correctly set (data_ column).

Best regards